# Computing the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$ at $p_0=[1:1:1]$ and then at $p=[1:0:0]$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In computing the blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^2$, it is not too difficult to see that we get a subset of $\mathbb{P}^2\times\mathbb{P}^2$ as specified on the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowing_up).

I would like to consider blowing up the blow-up, but at the point corresponding to where $[1:0:0]$ is after having blown it up at $p_0=[1:1:1]$. I know there's the general construction of blow-ups of schemes, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around computing an explicit equation of the blow-up.

Maybe to note, I haven't spent too much time thinking about blow-ups in explicitly. Hartshorne does not really go through much of that and I have not found a reference on algebraic geometry that goes into all of the details with the computations. A reference would help a lot as well. I think Eisenbud and Harris has something to say, but I'll need to look it up in the meantime.

Comment: Properly speaking the blowup of $\mathbb P^2$ at a point lives in $\mathbb P^2 \times \mathbb P^{2\vee}$ (because the latter parametrizes the lines in the former), but you can actually replace the second factor with the $\mathbb P^1$ of lines through a point, allowing you to express the blowup as a hypersurface. Generally, more complex blowups will have higher codimension in their ambient spaces AND often not be complete intersections. I suppose part of the question is what do you mean by "compute the blowup"? Finding equations is unpleasant, but e.g. describing curves on the surface is not.

Comment: @TabesBridges I mean finding equations. There's a paper I'm looking at that blows up $\mathbb{P}^2$ a few times to construct a particular surface. I would like to be able to describe said surface more explicitly (this is the hard part), but this likely entails computing the equations of the blow-up.

Comment: Can you link the paper?

Comment: @TabesBridges https://arxiv.org/pdf/1210.4633.pdf   The part of interest is at the top of page 3.

Comment: OK, so the blowup in $8$ points would live inside $\mathbb P^2$ multiplied by $8$ copies of $\mathbb P^1$, meaning you would need minimum $8$ equations to cut it out and probably more. Can I ask what you are trying to so with this surface? I don't see how the equations would help you understand anything the author is doing, at least in that section.

Comment: @TabesBridges It is for a project atm where we're trying to find explicit equations of certain interesting surfaces. We're probably not going to need to find explicit equations of said del Pezzo surface, but I was curious on what the process would look like.